# WASM page in Wordpress website

Tags: pages, javascript

I used [emscripten](https://emscripten.org/) to generate some html/js/wasm/data files and would like to add that as a page to my (Wordpress) website. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: It just generates some .html and .js files? If you want to embed this into an existing page then you could write a short plugin that contains the files and defines a shortcode to emit the HTML and [enqueue]() the JavaScript; if you want to include the generated HTML as a page as-is then you could create a specific template in your theme for the page by slug and just put the HTML in there.

Comment: @Rup Thanks for the advice. I can limit it to just HTML and Javascript, but it would be much slower than if I used the WebAssembly and data files.

Comment: Right, sorry, I don’t know enscripten. You can include any files you want, yes, but you’d need to wire it up with HTML and JS I’d imagine?

Comment: @Rup Right; the HTML calls the JS which runs the WASM and loads the .data, at least that's my understanding of it.